# Is it possible to make a wifi hotspot be on the same 'network' as a shared etherent connection

Tags: networking, ip, wifi-hotspot

I am testing out a file server idea on a ancient (32bit!) computer running CentOS 7.

So far I have managed to lazily configure the ethernet interfaces to work through NetworkManager ([though wifi doesn't exist for it at the moment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317741/make-networkmanager-manage-a-interface)), in the following configuration:

[image: network diagram - basically the file server has to NICs, one connecting it to a router, the other to client PCs through a switch]

The `10.42.0.1` is a shared IPv4 network (currently) managed by network manager. If I can add a working wireless interface to the file server, is it possible to add it to the shared network so that wireless devices connected to the file server can also access the other computers directly? (so both wired Client PCs and wireless devices will see the the File Server as `10.42.0.1`, and the wireless devices will be able to access the Client PCs IP address (e.g. `10.42.0.52`) directly and vice-versa.

Comment: Future note, this seems to happen automatically when setup up using NetworkManager in Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can bind the network sources together into one network connection.which will also give you fail over if one of the connections fails to connect.

Linux should provide fail over for the network automaticly. And bind it but it will list each connection seprately.